# @synthesize syntax when overriding accessors

Tags: objective-c, accessor

I am doing a value object / Entity, that holds data for my model.
I get the data from a web service as JSON, now, instead of moving all the different objects from the parsed JSON over into different properties on my Entity. i.e. reading out the NSString for the @"name" key and setting it to `[Entity setName:[JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]` etc. My Entity has one actual property, 
`NSDictionary *dataDictionary`, this property hold the JSON dictionary as it left the parser.

Now when I need the name value I write an accessor that looks like this:

```
- (NSString*) name {
    return [self.dataDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

This is nice, I don't have to do any work unless there is a request for that particular property.

Now my question is how do I best tell the compiler that the accessor exists, but does not hold a "real" property.
I have this in my interface:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

And the `@synthesize` in my implementation, but this seems to create an overhead in my logic. Objective C will, as far as I understand, make a room in memory for me to store an object of type NSString when I do the `@property(nonatomic, retain)` and technically I don't need this as I am already storing this value in the the `NSDictionary *dataDictionary`

If I make it `@dynamic` I guess I would also have to provide a setter, which I would never need.

**So, Is there a syntax that lets me create the illusion to all objects accessing the Entity that these are "normal" properties, but internally in the Entity not alloc/store unnecessary objects or write more code than is needed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a `name` method in your interface, not a property.

```
- (void)name;
```

Comment: Yes, of course:), much better. I was overcomplicating it, I then always have the option of doing a - (void) setName:(NSString*) if I need it down the line. Thanks.

Comment: No worries @RickiG. That's effectively what a synthesized property does for your - create getter (and setter) methods based on a few variable parameters your provide.

Comment: Yes, so I was first asking the compiler to generate the accessors for me, then afterwards overriding them. Waste of electrons:) I guess there was no extra [value retain] because of the overriding, but method approach is much easier to read